# org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException when trying to connect with to Google Talk

Tags: java, android, xmpp, chat, smack

I'm trying to create simple chat application in android using xmpp and local server xampp to store database..
I followed this example :
http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-xmppjabber-chat-application-for.html
but i don't know how to connect to my local server from smack or from my app (because i don't understand what is that Service field he used in the example) so i tried to connect to Google talk..
I tried gmail.com, talkx.l.google.com, talk.google.com in the Host field but i get in the log cat :

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException
```

and when i try to log connection i get null.. 
Any idea ? :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know real problem on your app but i can referance some resources for running examples :

if you want to make it on your own server : [this](http://im-a-developer-too.blogspot.ca/2014/04/creating-android-xmpp-client-using.html) is a good example .

if you want to make it with Google Talk Server : [this](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119) is a good example .

you should use a asmack.jar and add it to your build path by right click -> build path -> add build path